# Expander inside ListBox not showing content when expanded the first time from binding

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, data-binding

I have a dialog window that contains a `ListBox` whose ItemTemplate contains an expander. 
Its `IsExpanded` is bound to a property in the item view model. The `ListBoxItem`'s `IsSelected` property is also bound to the `IsExpanded` property in the item view model object. And finally the `SelectedItem` property of the `ListBox` is bound to a property with the same name in the view model.

The problem here is that when setting up the view model before showing the dialog and setting it to the `DataContext` of the dialog, the item in the listbox gets selected as it should, the expander arrow shows that it is in the expanded state, but the content of the expander is not displayed.

If I set up the view model *after* showing the dialog, eg. in the Loaded handler of the dialog things work as expected.  What is going on here, and what would be the best way to fix it?

The dialog window is defined as:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Dialog"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       xmlns:l="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
       Title="Dialog" Height="300" Width="300">
  <Grid>
     <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
              <Expander Header="Expander" x:Name="MyExpander" IsExpanded="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}">
                 <Rectangle Width="100" Height="20" Fill="Red" />
              </Expander>
           </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
           <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
              <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
           </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
     </ListBox>
  </Grid>
```

And the **ViewModel** (implementation not included for the sake of brevity):

```
public interface IMyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   object SelectedItem { get; set; }
   ObservableCollection<IMyItemViewModel> Items { get; }
}

public interface IMyItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   bool IsExpanded { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have a simple main window with a button, and its `Click` handler is defined as:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   MyViewModel vm = new MyViewModel();
   MyItemViewModel item = new MyItemViewModel();
   vm.Items.Add(item);
   vm.SelectedItem = item;

   Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
   dialog.DataContext = vm;
   dialog.ShowDialog();
}
```

When I run the application and click the button, the dialog shows up, the expander arrow indicates that it is in the expanded state, but its content is not displayed. Clicking on the expander collapses it, and clicking it again expands it, this time showing the content.
Putting the same code directly in the Main Window instead of a dialog however works as it is supposed to.

If I just do a `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => vm.SelectedItem = item);` instead of setting it directly things also seem to work, but this feels a bit shaky.

What can be done to fix this problem?

Comment: I would try registering to ListBox.selectionChange event and check the also try using snoop and check your binding data when the content isnt shown

Comment: It seems that ababyron is correct in his assumtion that it is a measurement bug of some sort, because all the properties of the content are actually set correctly when viewed in Snoop or in debug mode, it is just that the content is not displayed on screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the content of the expander is not measured again after it is loaded, if the `IsExpanded` property is already set to true. Or to put it another way, the content is measured when it has still no actual size.

I suppose the easiest solution would be to just set the `SelectedItem` once the dialog has been loaded:

```
dialog.Loaded += (s, x) => vm.SelectedItem = item;
```

Comment: Hmm.. isn't this sort of a bug in WPF then?

Comment: If my assumption is correct, then it is a case that is not correctly handled by the framework. So yes, you could call that a bug.

Comment: You could even log the bug at MS Connect (connect.microsoft.com). The WPF Measure system is a complex bit of code; XAML is able to describe conditions they didn't capture in their unit tests. You hit one of them; the Expander is not a particularly robust control, in my view.

Comment: Yeah, it seems that way. Or perhaps it is the ListBoxItem's fault. Either way, I filed a bug at https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/787178/expander-in-wpf-not-measuring-properly-when-inside-a-listbox-and-set-via-binding-before-listbox-is-shown#details